# Our company's website is IPv6 ready. What all testing I should perform?

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, test-planning, windows

Our company's website is mostly static.

For Example we have:

1. Home Page
2. About Us
3. Partners
4. Career
5. Join Us

Join Us - we collect the data and call back potential leads.

This website is said to be IPv6 ready. Me and Boss don't know what does it mean by IPv6 ready, what to test and what not and what will be obsoleted?

We decided to do Sanity of existing functionality but still doubting that will that be enough?

**Question: What we are missing? What else we should test?**
Maybe - Sanity on Cross Browser, Cross Platform also.

Answer (score 2):

I think that just means that your DNS have the records mapping the host name to IPv6 address. No special functional testing is required since it is a network layer change. You can use the sites like [this](https://ready.chair6.net/) to test if IPv6 connectivity to you site can be established.

Answer (score 1):

Most often IPv6 ready means that the webservers have been **configured** to support IPv6 only traffic. Test a page loads from a IPv6 only connection, or use tools like Alexey R. suggested.

If the code was changed for this IPv6 support, maybe you need to test more. Do a risk assessment with the one whomever implemented the change.

My guess would be that if you can reach the site then you are done, any other testing sounds overkill. But if you do not know what IPv6 is, maybe read up on it first before you make an decision.